# Delphi 7 -> Unable Loading an Image from a Resource file

Tags: delphi, image, resources, bitmap, delphi-7

I've been looking hours over the net, using Google, trying for PDF's and still unable 
to load an Image resource in Delphi 7..

My **test.rc** file goes like this:

```
1 RT_BITMAP "1.bmp"
```

I've added the **test.rc** file to my project using **Project->Add to Project..** which compiled a **test.res** file upon build and seems to have automatically included the **.res** file into my project (because using the **{$R test.res}** would say I already use that resource). I also tried removing the **test.res** from the project using **Project->Remove from Project..** and manually adding the **{$R test.res}** to my project.

However no matter how I include the **test.res** file..
I get the

> Project Project2.exe raised exception
>   class EAccessViolation with message
>   'Access violation at address  00408D0C
>   in module 'Project2.exe'. Read of
>   address 00000001'. Process stopped.
>   Use Step or Run to  continue.

at First I used

```
Image1.Picture.Bitmap.LoadFromResourceID(hInstance,1);
```

Because this is what I found using Google. And I got this error. 
Later I tried

```
procedure TForm1.Image1Click(Sender: TObject);
var bBitmap : TBitmap;
begin

 bBitmap := TBitmap.Create;
 try

  bBitmap.Handle := LoadBitmap(hInstance, '1');
  Image1.Width := bBitmap.Width;
  Image1.Height := bBitmap.Height;
  Image1.Canvas.Draw(0,0,bBitmap);
 finally

  bBitmap.Free;
end;


end;
```

This didn't get me any errors, and nither did it show the image so the problem remains unsolved..

I'm a newbie to the use of Resources but I must load some images into resources before I release my project so the **.BMP** files won't be tempered with...

any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Back to basics, why do you need to do this? why don't you just assign the bitmap into the image at design time? Or, if you want some kind of dynamic loading, why don't you use a TImageList and load from there the selected image at runtime?

Comment: My *.rc files contain lines like `IDB_BLUBB BITMAP DISCARDABLE "Blubb.bmp"`, i.e. resource type `BITMAP` not `RT_BITMAP`. Maybe this is the culprit.

Comment: @PA- I'm having a visual interface of a machine. The only way I could use a TImageList more than once , is load a default .bmp file to the image componenet and only then load another image from the imagelist(because onces you loaded an image from TImageList, you can't load another to the same image componenet); I need that default BMP image file in a resource so it won't get tempered with

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I reproduced exactly your same problem in a test program.

I then changed `RT_BITMAP` to `BITMAP`, recompiled RC and tested.

It works.

Comment: Awesome! :) Thanks a lot! What I did is have my .RC files modified the same way you suggeseted (Replace RT_BITMAP with BITMAP only). And using only -one statement- to load the resource: Image1.Picture.Bitmap.LoadFromResourceID(hInstance, 1); That got the job done! No farther additions were needed. - Using Delphi 7 Pro. Thanks PA, you have no idea how much you helped me with this one! :)

Comment: P.S - I loaded the .rc file using Project->Add to Project.. - I truly hope this will help others who encounter this.